# shell script to extract the name and IP address

Tags: bash, sh

Is there a way to use shell script to get only the name and net from the result as below:

Result

```
6cb7f14e-6466-4211-9a09-2b8e7ad92703 | name-erkoev4ja3rv                              | 2e3900ff36574cf9937d88223403da77 | ACTIVE | Running     | net0=10.1.1.2; ing-net=10.1.1.3; net=10.1.1.4;
```

Expected Result

```
name-erkoev4ja3rv: 10.1.1.4
```

Comment: yes there should be. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ input="6cb7f14e-6466-4211-9a09-2b8e7ad92703 | name-erkoev4ja3rv                              | 2e3900ff36574cf9937d88223403da77 | ACTIVE | Running     | net0=10.1.1.2; ing-net=10.1.1.3; net=10.1.1.4;"

$ echo "$input"  | sed -E 's,^[^|]+ \| ([^ ]+).* net=([0-9.]+).*$,\1: \2,g'
name-erkoev4ja3rv: 10.1.1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "6cb7f14e-6466-4211-9a09-2b8e7ad92703 | name-erkoev4ja3rv                              | 2e3900ff36574cf9937d88223403da77 | ACTIVE | Running     | net0=10.1.1.2; ing-net=10.1.1.3; net=10.1.1.4;"  | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}{print $13}'
```

Does this satisfy your case?

Comment: Close,I need to get the ip address by the "net" key word instead of fixed column.